# Best way to transmit XML between servers using Zend Framework

Tags: xml, zend-framework, rest

I'm trying to come up with a clean way to send xml from one server to another in a secure method that would use some sort of authentication and be able to return responses and handle multiple chunks of data per connection,

I've tried using the Zend_Rest stuff but it doesn't look like its going to be any use when I want to send large chunks of structured data, am I wrong?

I'm after a decent amount of guidance for a given solution as I seem to be creating rabbit holes with all my various failed attempts.

Thanks in advanced,
Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use Zend_Soap_Server over HTTPS with username/password OR some secure hash (generated maybe somewhere entirely else) sent as params.